# regex email validation django

Tags: regex, django

Working on a project for school I know how to do this in flask but learning django. I am trying to make sure that a valid email is entered before it post. If I do not do the if else statement the form goes though but wont validate it. I have the following and the only part not working is the one part with comments but I included the whole views.py incase you see something at top that could be wrong.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import User
import re
EMAIL_REGEX = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9.+_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$')

# Create your views here.
def index(request):

    return render(request, "emailvalidation/index.html" )


def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':                                    #here down

        if len(request.form['email']) < 1:
            add_message("Invalid Email Address!")                  #if i take out the if else the form does work 
        elif not EMAIL_REGEX.match(request.form['email']):              #the validation.
            add_message("Invalid Email Address!")
        else:
            User.objects.create(email = request.POST['email'] )     #to here


        context ={

            "email": User.objects.all(),
        }

    return render(request, 'emailvalidation/success.html' ,context)




the traceback error

Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/user

Django Version: 1.10.6
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
['apps.emailvalidation',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\django2\emailval\emailval\apps\emailvalidation\views.py" in create
  15.       if len(request.form['email']) < 1:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /user
Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'form'
```

Comment: What does your url patterns look like?

Comment: Instead of creating your own pattern, you should take a look at this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/#validate-email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request` does not have a `form` attribute. Since you already have `if request.method == "POST"` - you can safely do the following:

change

```
request.form['email']
```

with

```
request.POST['email']
```

Ideally, you should be using [django forms for handing the validations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#forms-in-django) etc. Django forms have better validation logic, regex validators, etc..

Comment: LOL ty thats what happens when you go from flask to django in two weeks.