# Email address verification via RegEx or Django built-in

Tags: regex, django, python-2.7

So I have spent the last hour looking at links for dango email address validation. What I am trying to do is to take the `def create(request)` area. Pass the email address submitted from the `request.POST['email']`,  have it checked to be a valid email address before its added to my database. I have email regex installed. I know there is a built-in one for Django and I can get them coded without breaking my page but they seem to  don't work correctly: when I put in a fake email address, it doesn't catch it. Would someone give me the best way to code this out?  While I had a form post issue earlier, this form goes through but does not validate the email

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import User
from django.contrib import messages
import re
EMAIL_REGEX = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9.+_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$')

# Create your views here.
def index(request):

    return render(request, "emailvalidation/index.html" )


def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':  

        User.objects.create(email = request.POST['email'] )    


        context ={

            "email": User.objects.all(),

        }

    return render(request, 'emailvalidation/success.html' ,context)
```

Comment: What do you define as a fake email? Do you mean when an email doesn't exist? You could solve this by sending a confirmation email to the user. However anybody could easily use something like [10minutemail.com](https://10minutemail.com).

Comment: When they enter there email I want it to verify that the emailspot is not blank. And that the email they entered is valid ie anything @anthing .com

Comment: But you already successfully did that in your last question using `EMAIL_REGEX.match(request.POST['email'])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex email validation django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868652/regex-email-validation-django)

Comment: yea my last question fixed the process going though. The code was good code but it did not validate the email. So no not validation I would have asked you on last one but rules are new question. Ie the post processed and added to database but if I put a messed up email in there like just 'hi'  it still goes though

Comment: [But your regex works.](https://regex101.com/r/YmMwdL/1)

Comment: The code is good yes but its not stoping it from going though ie the regex or messages arent stopping it im still working on it ill post if i fix it. or someone else can

Comment: @David, couldd you clarify what exactly email address you try as fake and what exactly you see?

Comment: any form of anything  i could type dog and it just goes to the success page and adds dog to the database

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the verification in the wrong place. Need to do it in models.